# ektron 8.6 - override mobile device for a single session

Tags: ektron

A user can be routed to a mobile template of an existing desktop template based on what device they're on -- no problems there.

The difficulty I'm having is when I'd like to route a user from Template A (the mobile version) to Template B (the desktop version). A good example of this is a "view desktop version" link.

Is there a way to ask Ektron to ignore (for the length of the session) the device routing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually find the answer to this question on Ektron's customer portal. See this article:

[How To: Viewing a "Desktop" Site on a Mobile Device](https://portal.ektron.com/KB/10201/)

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't seem to be that elegant of a solution (setting a cookie to reflect preferences) but I suppose it'll work.